# OpenCV : findcontours() , too much external contours

Tags: c++, opencv

I want to find all contours of apples, but when I use contours.size(), the number of contours is more than the number of apples.

The following are the picture used to find contours and the picture which I draw contours on it,and the result of program.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z9Gkj.jpg)

Here are the codes.

```
//Contours  
vector<vector<Point>> contours,hull;
vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;
RNG rng(12345);
findContours(con, contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_EXTERNAL, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_NONE);

cout<<"contours.size(): "<<contours.size()<<endl;
cout<<"hierarchy.size(): "<<hierarchy.size()<<endl;


//draw contours and calculate areas
int area[10];
int currentareaCounted = 0;

for(int i = 0; i<contours.size()-1; i++){

    Scalar color = Scalar( rng.uniform(0, 255), rng.uniform(0, 255), 255);
    drawContours(contoursImg, contours, i, color, 2, 8, hierarchy);

    Mat drawingMatCount = cv::Mat::zeros(src_color.rows,src_color.cols, CV_8UC1);
    drawContours(drawingMatCount, contours, i, 255, -1, 8);
    currentareaCounted = countNonZero(drawingMatCount);

    area[i]=currentareaCounted;


    cout<<i<<"'th area "<<" : "<<currentareaCounted<<endl;
}
```

I am confused why the contous.size() is 7. It makes me use contours.size()-1 in the loop which I used to drawcontours, otherwise , the program will break.

If anyone finds any mistake, hope to tell me. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

first, you must found boundRect and then you can draw Contours like that code

```
for (int i = 0; i < validContours.size(); i++)
{
        if (boundRect[i].area() < 50)continue;

        rectangle(fin, boundRect[i].tl(), boundRect[i].br(), color, 2, 8, 0);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your opinion. I find that I can't find boundRect , and my contours[i].size() is weird. Is contours[i].size() represent the number of points in i'th contour? If it is , I am confused that contours.size() explodes.
The first size looks OK, but the second or third size explodes.Just like below.
contours[0].size()=200, contours[1].size()=515,contours[2].size()=106128452

Comment: No, I have not solved it yet. I have no idea how to do.

Comment: I tried other pictures with apples in different numbers. Then I found that if all edges are captured correctly , like the picture on the left that white parts are the apples , the number smaller or equal to 3 is normal. It means its contours.size() is correct. But if the number is more than 3 , the contours.size() is the correct number plus 1. It is really weird.